# Searching for a string inside of an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, if-statement

The project I am currently working on is for a personal lending library app. The user can add objects, MediaItems, to an array, and can assign values to the object's fields for title, format, onLoan, etc.

The problem I am currently having is when I search the array for a specific item. No matter what I put in for the seach criteria, it always comes back true. I think I'm missing a piece of code somewhere, because it's almost as if the program isn't actually looking at the context of the string to see if it matches. Here is my program:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TrippelTylerPersonalLendingLibrary {

   //Fields
   MediaItem[] items = new MediaItem[100];
   int numberOfItems = 0;

   //Methods
   int displayMenu() {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       int choice;
       System.out.print("\nMenu\n" +
            "1. Add new item\n" +
            "2. Mark an item as on loan\n" +
            "3. List all items\n" +
            "4. Mark an item as returned\n" +
            "5. Quit\n\n" +
            "What would you like to do?");
       choice = input.nextInt();
       if(choice<1 || choice>5) {
           while(choice<1 || choice>5) {
               System.out.println("You have entered an invalid menu choice.\n" +
                    "What would you like to do?");
               choice = input.nextInt();
           }
           return choice;
       }
       else {
           return choice;
       }
   }

   void addNewItem(String title, String format) {
       String titleNew = title;
       String formatNew = format;
       MediaItem newItem = new MediaItem(titleNew, formatNew);
       items[numberOfItems] = newItem;
       numberOfItems= numberOfItems + 1;
   }

   void markItemOnLoan(String title, String name, String date) {
       String itemTitle=title;
       String person=name;
       String itemDate=date;
       for(int i=0; i<items.length;i++) {
           if(itemTitle == items[i].title) {
               items[i].onLoan = true;
               items[i].dateLoaned = itemDate;
               items[i].loanedTo = person;
           }
           else{
               System.out.println("I'm sorry, I couldn't find " + itemTitle + 
                    " in the library.");
           }
       }
   }

   String[] listAllItems() {

   }

   void markItemReturned(String title) {

   }

   //Main method
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       TrippelTylerPersonalLendingLibrary instance = new TrippelTylerPersonalLendingLibrary();
       MediaItem instance2 = new MediaItem();


       //Fields for main method
       int choice;
       int repeat = 1;
       String newTitle;
       String newFormat;
       String name;
       String date;
       boolean loaned;

       while(repeat == 1) {
          choice = instance.displayMenu();
          if(choice == 1) {
             newTitle = instance2.setTitle();
             newFormat = instance2.setFormat();
             instance.addNewItem(newTitle, newFormat);
          }
          else if(choice == 2) {
             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
             String titleToLoan;
             name=instance2.setLoanedTo();
             date=instance2.setDateLoaned();
             loaned=instance2.setOnLoan();
             titleToLoan= input.nextLine();
             instance.markItemOnLoan(titleToLoan, name, date);
          }
       }
   }

}
```

In the main method, when choice == 2, it calls `markItemOnLoan()` and passes through Strings based on what the user types in. Even if I type in something completely wrong, it never makes it to the else statement in the `markItemOnLoan` method. Do I need to change the way I am searching for the string?

Thanks everyone!,

Tyler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if(itemTitle.equals(items[i].title)) is the correct way.
.because == only compare  primitive data types such as int.to compare object data types you should use .equals method  example "hi".equals("hi") is true

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! It really helped clarify why Autocrab's response was correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(itemTitle.equals(items[i].title))
```

Comment: You should explain your answer a bit instead of only writing a one-liner of code.